# "System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down" not WSL

Tags: systemd, iptables, docker

When I install docker and try to run it, `sudo systemctl start docker`, it says it can't run as the title says.(Not WSL)

So when I run it with the `sudo service docker start` command, it turns off again after a second

Furthermore, `sudo dockerd` says that the modules bridge, br_netfilter, and ip_tables are installed but missing.
`iptables --wait -L -n` command also gives an error...

The Docker daemon failed to initialize the network controller, which seems to be related to the missing modules and iptables configuration issues mentioned earlier

---

my linux release is

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
distrib_release=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"
```

Comment: Hmm... so what *is* your init system? Perhaps `cat /proc/1/cmdline` or `xargs -0a /proc/1/cmdline` would be helpful

Comment: I'm not sure if I typed the commands correctly, but they both output `/bin/bash`

Comment: So that suggests your system was booted via something like `init=/bin/bash` from the grub recovery menu?

Comment: PID 1 process seems to run /bin/bash instead of systemd or init

Comment: Yeah I can see that - I'm just wondering how that's possible. Is `/sbin/init` actually a symlink to `/bin/bash`, or is the normal init being overridden via grub?

Comment: I'm using a rented server, so I don't know the detailed initial setup..... :(

I need to install docker but the server settings are weird and I'm stumped